# Why modifier in the source object is not working for the main system of particle system?

Tags: modifiers

I have created a cube system containing lots of spheres with particle-system and emitter option. But now I am trying to give some shakiness to all of the individual spheres. That is why I gave the parent object a noise modifier. But when I run the animation, only that single source object is vibrating not all the spheres in the object. This confuses me as I can see changing the color of the source object is changing the system's objects but why not this modifier. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: The animation data is tied to the object, not to the underlying geometry. When you instance the mesh as a particle, it doesn't inherit the animation data. Maybe there's a setting for it though I'm a bit rusty on particle systems

Answer (score 2):

In the *Render* settings for particles, you can enable different things for *Instanced Objects*:

- *Global Coordinates*
- *Object Rotation*
- *Object Scale*

You have to enable the necessary options if you want to use any of the modifications on position, rotation or scale of the object you're instancing since they are simulated for the particles and so usually overwritten. But note that for example the noise you are animating on the object will be exactly the same for each instance.

[image: partticle instance settings]

Comment: This was actually a very helpful suggestion. But one issue is now all the atoms in the cube are vibrating in the same manner. For the effect of atoms vibrate in solid materials I need those spheres to vibrate randomly. 

I know one way is to change the cube into the mesh and then individually place the noise modifier on each sphere but that would be so time-consuming for hundreds of spheres.

Do you know any other way I can achieve random vibration for thousands of spheres in the cube? I tried some force fields (turbulence) but didn't get what I want.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah, all are the same as I wrote in my answer, since they are all instances of a single object with its single animation. I cannot give you a complete explanation right now, but instead of animating the object, I would  think you should do it in Geometry Nodes by positioning the instances with an animated noise texture so that each has its own random movement. This tutorial by CGMatter is about other stuff but he uses random movement through noise texture: [Abstract Boolean](https://youtu.be/_Zcctus1M3Q)

Comment: Finally got what I wanted... Thanks a lot...